# How to separate application config from AP in container on Kuberetes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, websphere-liberty

I want to deploy a application which use an extenal config on Kubernetes. I built a spring boot application to a war file and put it into websphere liberty. Then put application.properties in `/config/config` ( `/config` is shortcut of `/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer`) which I want my application to  use.
I write a Dockerfile as below:

```
FROM websphere-liberty:19.0.0.6-javaee8
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /ibank-pv && chown -R 1001:0 /ibank-pv
RUN mkdir -p /config/config/ && chown -R 1001:0 /config/config
COPY --chown=1001:0 ibank.war /config/apps/
COPY --chown=1001:0 server.xml /config
COPY --chown=1001:0 application.properties /config/config/
USER 1001
CMD ["/opt/ibm/wlp/bin/server","run","defaultServer"]
```

Here is my `server.xml`. I set `${server.config.dir}/config` as a config resource folder.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">
    <featureManager>
        <feature>javaee-8.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <basicRegistry id="basic" realm="BasicRealm">
        <!-- <user name="yourUserName" password="" />  -->
    </basicRegistry>

    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443" />

    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

    <library id="configResources">
        <folder dir="${server.config.dir}/config" />
    </library>

    <application location="ibank.war">
        <classloader privateLibraryRef="configResources" />
    </application>
</server>
```

And I add these code to read the application.properties in `${server.config.dir}/config`.

```java
public class IbankServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526471155622776147L;

    private final Properties config;

    public IbankServlet() throws Exception {
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
        config = new Properties();
        config.load(is);
    }

}
```

However, when I start the server my application, it still read the `application.properties` which is in war file. What I have to do let my application use `application.properties` in `${server.config.dir}/config`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the issue that [`getClass().getResourceAsStream("relative-path")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) looks in the Java package of that specified class? That is, whatever subdirectory corresponds to the Java package of `IbankServlet`. In other words, is your `application.properties` within the WAR file buried down in a package subdirectory?

If so, you'll need to either change to `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/application.properties")` (with the leading slash), and move it to the classpath root in your WAR file, or have your Docker file copy it down into the correct subdirectory.

However, if your `IbankServlet` is actually not in a Java package at all, this probably isn't the issue.)

(But also, I admit, I'm not certain of the precedence if a file exists in both your WAR and in a "shared library".)

Comment: Thanks. It works after I remove the config file in WAR. But, there is a new problem that I can not connect my application. The url I used is http://<mycluster.ip>:<NodePort>/ibank.